# Sharepoint and multiple workflows

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, custom-lists

I am designing a workflow for an absence request at my company. The problem is that whenever I to test the workflow, I don't know if it is SD or MOSS, but it creates a new instance of the workflow. It looks like this:

Workflow Name (click to change settings)-----------------Workflows in Progress

Review Absence---------------------------------------------------------------0
Review Absence (Previous Version:6/23/2009 10:39:45 AM)---------0

Common sense told me, "all right let's erase both or multiple instances of the workflow and let SharepointDesigner create a new instance of the Absence request workflow".... FAIL!

I modified values in the workflow so I can know it was a new generated workflow, but when I create a new request those variables do not update.

Any ideas?

Thank You very much! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you click Finish and save your workflow using SharePoint Designer, it creates a new Instance of it attached to the list. I think the reason it does this, is in case you have workflows using the now "old" version that are currently running.

What I usually do is clean up the older workflows by removing any with the "(Previous version: ...)". This leaves only the latest workflow instance on your list. I don't think you want to remove the 1st entry, "Review Absence", because that is the one you just saved!

Comment: Thank you I will try tomorrow morning, I wish I could finish it by 2morrow.